# Is it possible to combine multiple SQL statements that use different WHERE clauses and LIMITs into one statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently coding a Yu-Gi-Oh! "booster pack" opening simulator. You open a pack of 9 cards but each pack needs to be "weighted".

The logic is as follows:

- Guaranteed 7 Commons.
- Guaranteed 1 Rare.
- Guaranteed either 1 common or any rarity above Rare.

So naturally I have this split into 3 consecutive SQL statements:

```
SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr, card_list cd 
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Common'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
AND cr.id = cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7

SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr, card_list cd 
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Rare'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
AND cr.id = cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr, card_list cd 
WHERE cr.set_rarity != 'Rare'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
AND cr.id = cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Would there possibly be a more optimal way of achieving this? The statements aren't taking long to run but I feel like the code might be longer than is necessary. Or maybe I'd be better off applying the logic in PHP and passing the rest onto SQL after?

Comment: If you have the same column for each select you can try to use `UNION` or in PHP you can select all cards and select some random cards in each result array (your choice if people can have double or not)

Comment: There is a possible problem with your logic in that the last query may return a card which was also returned by the first query. I don't know the game well enough to know if that's an issue...

Comment: @Nick you are actually correct and it's something I didn't spot. I could add every result from the first query to an array and tell the last query to also ignore everything found in that array.

Comment: @GenesisBits it might be simpler to read all the cards with the appropriate `set_code` and filter them in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`.

By the way, `SELECT ... FROM table1, table2` is a deprecated way to write join since about 25 years.

```
(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr
JOIN card_list cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Common'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7)

UNION

(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr
JOIN card_list cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Rare'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)

UNION

(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity 
FROM rarities_db cr
JOIN card_list cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity != 'Rare'
AND cr.set_code like '%lob%'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```